# The relationship between covariance and inner product

Tags: probability

It looks like covariance has some relationship between inner product. I have checked that covariance is bilinear and symmetric, but not positive definite (it is positive semi-definite). Although in WIKI, there are some information about the relationship between covariance and inner product, I still cannot really get the point. Hope someone will give me a more detailed answer about the relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with finite second moments on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F ,P)$  and $L^{2}$ is the space of square integrable random variables on $(\Omega, \mathcal F ,P)$ with the inner product $ \langle X, Y \rangle=EXY$ then covariance of $X$ and $Y$ is the inner product of $X-EX$ and $Y-EY$.

Comment: Very appreciate for your answer. But since I haven't learn advanced probability yet, which makes me hard to understand what "finite second moment on probability space" means. Would you mind explaining more about it or give me some advice how to learn it?

Comment: @AlexanderWang Well, $EXY$ is an inner product for random variables and covariance is the inner product of $X-EX$ and $Y-EY$.

Comment: Oh I see what "finite second moment" means. Excuse my poor English. I see your point and I finally understand what Wiki says. Thank you very much.